# Call other component Sencha Touch / Javascript

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to create something really simply, but I am somehow struggling with this.

It works in Sencha Architect 3, but it is giving me issues so I am trying to CMD way.
In Architect I created a Controller, but for some reason this didn't work.

So I am trying with a simple listener.

My Question is how do I call "MyContainer" from the Button Tap event, because "Refreshing..." doesn't appear?

I tried:

> MyContainer.setHtml('Refreshing...');

but this gave me: Uncaught ReferenceError: MyContainer is not defined

I also tried:

> this.getMyContainer().setHtml('Refreshing...');

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

and this:

> Ext.getElementById('MyContainer').setHtml('Refreshing...');

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

This is my MainView.js

> Ext.define('WebChat.view.Main', {
>
> ```
> extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
> xtype: 'main',
> requires: [
>     'Ext.TitleBar',
>     'Ext.Button'
> ],
> config: {
>
>  itemId: 'MainView',
>         items: [
>             {
>                 xtype: 'titlebar',
>                 docked: 'top',
>                 itemId: 'topBar',
>                 title: 'Obec Webchat',
>                 items: [
>                     {
>                         xtype: 'button',
>                         action: 'back',
>                         id: 'BackButton',
>                         itemId: 'BackButton',
>                         margin: '5 70% 5 15',
>                         ui: 'back',
>                         text: 'Home'
>                     }
>                 ]
>             },
>             {
>                 xtype: 'container',
>                 docked: 'top',
>                 height: '100%',
>                 html: '<iframe src="someurl" width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="yes"></iframe>',
>                 itemId: 'MyContainer',
>                 width: '100%'
>             }
>         ],
>         listeners: [
>             {
>                 fn: 'onBackButtonTap',
>                 event: 'tap',
>                 delegate: '#BackButton'
>             }
>         ]
>     },
>
> onBackButtonTap: function(button, e, eOpts) {
>     Ext.getElementsByTagName('MyContainer').SetHtml('Refreshing...');
> }
> ```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

`this.down('#MyContainer').setHtml('Foo');`

It's not a good idea to just make up method names see if they work (`Ext.getElementsByTagName`).

Comment: Thank that worked! :D
The getElementsByTagName was in the code completion from Sublime Text.

Answer (score -1):

Give `Ext.get('MyContainer').update('Refreshing...');`  a try.